# UPDATED: Only select certain item based on radio button and option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and I'm in a bit of a pickle.  I have 3 main radio buttons setup.  These buttons are to select an item based on the country selected.

So for example, I have 6 items.  3 for domestic (USA) and 3 for international (!=USA).

For example:  If I select first_radio, it also selects either something-div-0 or something-div-1 based on option selected.

JQuery (UPDATED)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.something').hide();


$('.somethingName :input').each(function (i, v) {
$(this).attr("id", "something-div-" + i);
i++;
});

$("#option").change(function() {

    var isUS = $("#option:selected").text() === 'UNITED STATES';
    var isNotUS = !isUS;

$(".somethingPick").click(function() {
if(isUS && $("#first_radio").prop('checked') === true){
    $('#something-div-0').click();
} else if(isUS && $("#second_radio").prop('checked') === true){
    $('#something-div-2').click();
} else if(isUS && $("#third_radio").prop('checked') === true){
    $('#something-div-4').click();
} else if(isNotUS && $("#first_radio").prop('checked') === true){
    $('#something-div-1').click(); 
} else if(isNotUS && $("#second_radio").prop('checked') === true){
    $('#something-div-3').click(); 
} else if(isNotUS && $("#third_radio").prop('checked') === true){
    $('#something-div-5').click();
});
});
}); 
</script>
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

I updated the JQuery in my jsfiddle.  I'm almost there.  I can get 3 of them working.  I just need help with the other 3.

Here''s my jsfiddle too:  https://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/r99qom5v/31/

Comment: do yourself a favor and store some of those boolean expressions as variables. `var isUS = $("#option:selected").text() === 'UNITED STATES'); if(isUS && ...)`

Comment: Thanks, wasn't thinking about that when typing it.  lol.  Do you know why the last 3 options won't work?

Comment: try having another variable that is `var isNotUS = !isUS;` and using that. `!(x === y)` might give different results than `x !== y`. I'm not super confident about the differences between `==` and `===`, etc

Comment: i tried the var isNotUS = !isUS; and var isUS = $("#option:selected").text() === 'UNITED STATES'); but it breaks the .hide() function.

Comment: breaks the `.hide()` function? are you defining them in the right order? you need to do `isUS` first. update your question with your new code.

Comment: First thing first - you don't need document.ready and $(function) both, they are same, only different notation. Keep all your code inside one of them. Assign the variables isUs and notUs inside document.ready as only then the dom is ready and you can read the controls. Then, Test your code , if it doesn't work then update your question with new code AND the HTML. If possible create a JSFIDDLE.

Comment: Thank you.  I made the changes and included the jsfiddle.

Comment: What exactly should happen in your demo? What steps should the user take to implement what effect?

Comment: There are 3 main radio buttons and 2 items associated with each one.  If you click 1 year and US as the select option, it selects US1.  If you click 1 year and OTHER as the select option, it selects NOTUS1.  It's also suppose to hide the items from view and only show the 3 main radio buttons.

Comment: There are so many problems with your jsfiddle.  your input tags should be self closed `<input />`, you have class declarations with space  `<div class = "something">`, things are misspelled, like one place you use "sometingPick" and another "somethingPick".  Fix all the little mistakes and it will be easier to debug.

Comment: crap, sorry about that

Comment: Here's the update one.  fixed the misspelled one, closed the input tags and removed the spaces.  https://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/r99qom5v/13/

Comment: Man.. you really need to work on your syntax.  You are missing a closing brace on the last `elseif` and also you shouldn't load jsfiddle via https as it is blocking jquery from loading to due protocol mismatch.  i fixed those things: http://jsfiddle.net/r99qom5v/14/ and it hides you divs now...

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude.. just that these things are basics and it's very important to be meticulous when writing any kind of code.  Otherwise it will be impossible to discover what's going wrong when 7 or 8 things are malfunctioning at once.

Comment: I must have deleted it by accident.  I had it before.  I don't take it personally.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are a couple other pointers.  Don't use `var isUS = $("#option:selected").text() === 'UNITED STATES';` when you can simply say `var isUS = $("#option").val() == 'UNITED STATES';`  And you probably need a `change` event for that select if you are expecting things to happen when it's changed.

Comment: would that need to be a separate function or can that be added to the click function?

Comment: Yeah it should be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r99qom5v/21/

Comment: ok.  I tried yours and I unhid the items to see if they were being selected and I'm not sure if it depends on the plugin or not.  I'm using 1.6.4 and it's not working for me.

Comment: I updated the JQuery in my jsfiddle. I'm almost there. I can get 3 of them working. I just need help with the other 3.

Here''s my jsfiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/r99qom5v/31/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your code works, but I see an error while loading jQuery 1.6.4:

[Blocked loading mixed active content into console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent)

Sincerely I don't know why it gave this error, so I changed jQuery version to last and it loads without problems.

However I slightly edited your code to be cleaner

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var isUS = $("#option").val() === 'UNITED STATES';
var isNotUS = !isUS;

$("#option").change(function() {
    isUS = $("#option").val() === 'UNITED STATES';
    isNotUS = !isUS;
    checkRadio();
});

$(".somethingPick").click(function() {
    checkRadio();
});

function checkRadio() {
    $('.something input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');

    if(isUS && $("#first_radio").prop('checked')){
        $('#US_1').click();
    } else if(isUS && $("#second_radio").prop('checked')){
        $('#US_2').click();
    } else if(isUS && $("#third_radio").prop('checked')){
        $('#US_3').click();
    } else if(isNotUS && $("#first_radio").prop('checked')){
        $('#NOTUS_1').click();
    } else if(isNotUS && $("#second_radio").prop('checked')){
        $('#NOTUS_2').click();
    } else if(isNotUS && $("#third_radio").prop('checked')){
        $('#NOTUS_3').click();
    }
}

});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpL71v91/).

Comment: The fiddle url specifies `https` as the protocol, but apparently if you select 'jQuery 1.6.4`, jsFiddle tries to get the script from `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js`, hence the mixed content error. If you specify `http` for the fiddle, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/r99qom5v/31/

Comment: i explained that in the comments.. though there are a lot of them so i can see why you missed it.